# Show that $\textbf F$ is a gradient field by giving a scalar function $f$ on $\Omega^+$ such that $\nabla f=\textbf F$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that $\textbf F$ is a gradient field by giving a scalar function $f$ on $\Omega^+$ such that $\nabla f=\textbf F$.

$\textbf F = (\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},0)$, 
$\Omega^+ = \{(x,y)|x,y>0\}$.

My attempt:

We must have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$, so I obtained that $f = -arctan(x/y)+g(y,z)$.

Also $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$, so I got that $f = arctan(y/x)+h(x,z)$.

And $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$ tells us that $f$ is in terms of $x$ and $y$.

But now I am stuck. How is it possible that $-arctan(x/y)+g(y,z)=arctan(y/x)+h(x,z)$?

Comment: I would like to add that for your last bit you should have $g(y,z)=g(y)$ and $h(x,z)=h(x)$

Comment: Notice that, for $x,y>0$, $\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan (x/y) \equiv \arctan(y/x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the comments from @ellya and @FH93, another way of tackling the problem is to move to polar coordinates.

Using
$$
  r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \theta = \tan^{-1}(y/x)
$$
we have
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} \\
                  \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta} \end{bmatrix}
$$
If we invert the Jacobian matrix and multiply it with the left hand side, we get
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore, $f = f(\theta) = \theta = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$.

Comment: Thanks! Why does it matter that $x,y>0$?

Comment: Those conditions help avoid complications arising from the undefined nature of the function at the origin (r = 0).